# The android permission BLUETOOTH_SCAN not working in android 12 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

when I running the my project showing this error

```
`D/BluetoothAdapter(25841): isLeEnabled(): ON
I/flutter (25841): Error starting scan.
E/flutter (25841): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(startScan, Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for android.content.AttributionSource@bb6a5b7c: GattService registerScanner, null, null)
E/flutter (25841): #0      BluetoothManager.scan (package:flutter_bluetooth_basic/src/bluetooth_manager.dart:85:7)
E/flutter (25841): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25841):
```

`

I added `

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30"
        tools:targetApi="donut" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30"
        tools:targetApi="donut" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30"
        tools:targetApi="31" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

`
this permissions in androidmanifest but still the same error is showing and not taking any blue tooth devices.

Comment: i have same issue

Comment: any solution or idea for correcting this

Comment: which package are you using for bluetooth

Comment: esc_pos_bluetooth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Remove` the `android:maxSdkVersion="30"` from your permission requests.

Using it like this limits the permission request to SDK version `30 and older`.

Also, you only need `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` and `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` for `SDK >30`. Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions) for more information.

Change your code to the following and it should work:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
        tools:targetApi="31" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" 
        android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
```

Comment: `tools:targetApi="31"` does not appear to be valid. Is that the right syntax?